# How to return an array of objects in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have two classes,  Program(main class) and Driver.What I am trying to do is allow the user to create a Driver through the command line however I can't seem to get the array to print out. I am new to c# and programming not certain that this is the best way around this so any ideas help. thanks

Main Class

```
public class Program    
{           
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Driver> MyDriver = new List<Driver>();
        for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {    
            Driver driver = new Driver();                   
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Drivers Name");
            string driverName = driver.Name(Console.ReadLine());    
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Drivers Occupation");
            string driverOccupation = driver.Occupation(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("How many claims does this driver have?");                 
            int noOfClaims = driver.Claim(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));                    
            Console.WriteLine("Your car details: \n " + driverName + " \n " + driverOccupation + "\n " + noOfClaims);    
            MyDriver.Add(new Driver());                  
        }

        foreach (Driver i in MyDriver)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Driver Details  " + MyDriver);
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Driver Class

```
public class Driver  
{
    //Properties
    private string driverName; 
    private string driverOccupation;  
    private DateTime driverDOB; 
    private DateTime claimDate;  
    private int noOfClaims;  

    public Driver()//Default Constructor
    {
        driverName = "";
        driverOccupation = "";
        driverDOB = DateTime.MinValue;// Default value 01/01/0001
        claimDate = DateTime.MinValue;// Default value
        noOfClaims = 0;  
    }

    public Driver(string name , string occupation , DateTime dateOfBirth , DateTime dateOfClaim, int claims)
    {
        driverName = name;
        driverOccupation = occupation;
        driverDOB = dateOfBirth;
        claimDate = dateOfClaim;
        noOfClaims = claims;
    }

    public string Name(string driverName)
    {
        return driverName;
    }

    public string Occupation (string driverOccupation)
    {
        return driverOccupation;         
    }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth(DateTime driverDOB) 
    {
        return driverDOB;       
    }

    public int Claim(int noOfClaims) 
    { 
        return noOfClaims;     
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format(driverName , driverOccupation , driverDOB , noOfClaims );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really be using properties with a private set here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
        for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {

            Driver driver = new Driver();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Drivers Name");
            string driverName = driver.Name(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Drivers Occupation");
            string driverOccupation = driver.Occupation(Console.ReadLine());



            Console.WriteLine("How many claims does this driver have?");

            int noOfClaims = driver.Claim(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));


            Console.WriteLine("Your car details: \n " + driverName + " \n " + driverOccupation + "\n " + noOfClaims);

           MyDriver.Add(new Driver());

        }
```

to this:

```
        Driver driver;   
        for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {



            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Drivers Name");
            string driverName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Drivers Occupation");
            string driverOccupation = Console.ReadLine();



            Console.WriteLine("How many claims does this driver have?");

            int noOfClaims = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            driver = new Driver(driverName, driverOccupation, noOfClaims );

            Console.WriteLine("Your car details: \n " + driverName + " \n " + driverOccupation + "\n " + noOfClaims);

           MyDriver.Add(driver);

        }
```

and in the driver class add this

```
public Driver(string name , string occupation , int claims)
{
    driverName = name;
    driverOccupation = occupation;
    driverDOB = DateTime.MinValue;
    claimDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    noOfClaims = claims;
}
```

The printing part should become this way:

```
  foreach (Driver i in MyDriver)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Driver Details  " + i.toString());
    }
```

Comment: still getting an error once the command line end the loop. System.Collection.Generic.List . as soon as the program goes to run the foreach it gets the text "Driver Details ", then that error beside it

Comment: You can check it now.

Comment: Still the same, think something with my get and sets as explained above, thanks anyways tho.

Comment: Of course, sorry I missed that. Check the edit.

Comment: the error is gone but the foreach prints out "Driver Details " followed by DriverApp.Driver. DriverApp is my namespace by the way

Comment: Got it working cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your print loop:

```
foreach (Driver i in MyDriver)
{
   Console.WriteLine(" Driver Details  " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
    foreach (Driver i in MyDriver)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Driver Details  " + MyDriver);
    }
```

should be changed to something like this:

```
    foreach (Driver driver in MyDriver)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Driver Details  " + driver.toString());
    }
```

Comment: He has ToString overridden for Driver, so no getDetails method necessary.

Comment: oops you're right ... I didn't scroll down :)